# $\forall v\in V:(Tv,v)=0\implies T^{\star}=-T$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a real inner product space and $T:V\to V$ a linear transformation. $$\forall v\in V, (Tv,v)=0\implies T^{\star}=-T$$

"An attempt":

$$(Tv,v)=(v,T^{\ast}v)=(T^{\ast}v,v)$$

Comment: Look at $v + w$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Daniel Fischer said because of the linearity of $T$, $T(v+w) = Tv + Tw$. Then we have :

$$
(T(v+w),v+w) = 0 = (Tv,v)+(Tw,w) + (Tv,w)+(Tw,v) = (Tv,w) + (T^*v,w) 
$$

which leads to

$$
\forall (v,w), 
(-Tv,w) = (T^*v,w)
$$