# $<L(v), v> = 0 $ for all $v$ if and only if $L + L* = 0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, adjoint-operators

How do I prove that <$L(v), v$>$ = 0$ for all $v$ if and only if $L + L$*$ = 0$. Here, $L$ * is the adjoint.

I did something like <$L(v), v$> = <$v, L*(v)$> then added the two to get the $L + L$*, but I don't really know how to proceed.

Comment: Which direction are you having trouble proving?

Comment: Also what is the context here? Is this a real inner product space?

Comment: Yup, real innter product space. Does <(L+L*)(v), v> = 0 for all v automatically imply that L+L* is 0?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2074368/why-does-the-fact-that-tv-is-orthogonal-to-v-for-all-v-implies-t-is-the-z).

Comment: See the answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/452802/forall-v-in-vtv-v-0-implies-t-star-t